# Entity DataSource control in a DynamicData app referencing an MVC CodeFirst project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datasource, dynamic-data, entitydatasource

I added a Dynamic Data web app as a second project to an MVC 3 app. The Dynamic Data app references the derived EF 4.1 Context in the MVC 3 app (code first).

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(
    new EFCodeFirstDataModelProvider(() => new MvcApplication1.Models.Context()),
    new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

I want to try out a Dynamic GridView control but I don't understand how to configure the DataSource control. The connection string from my MVC app didn't work for the control. Nothing shows up in the control's configuration wizard even after a build. I am totally webforms/datasource illiterate. Am I way off here? How do I do this?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.DynamicData.CustomPages.WebUserControl1" %>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>

<asp:DynamicDataManager ID="DynamicDataManager1" runat="server" />
    <DataControlReference ControlID="GridView1"/>
</asp:DynamicDataManager>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Seems like all the tutorials are 3-4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DD templates are way behind.

Add this to a file:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
public static class ModeContainer<OC> where OC : ObjectContext
{
    private static MetaModel model = new MetaModel();
    static ModeContainer() { model.RegisterContext(typeof(OC), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true }); }
    public static MetaModel Model { get { return model; } }
    public static MetaTable Table<EO>() where EO : EntityObject { return Model.Tables.First(x => x.EntityType == typeof(EO)); }
}
```

Then Global can contain this:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx")
{
    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert" }),
    Model = ModeContainer<ContactsModel.ContactsEntities>.Model
});
```

And then you can do things like this in a page to use dynamic outside of the route:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MetaTable table = ModeContainer<ContactsModel.ContactsEntities>.Table<Person>();
    GridView1.SetMetaTable(table);
}
```

Along side of grid and source like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Azure" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Contacts" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Addresses" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ContactsEntities" DefaultContainerName="ContactsEntities" EntitySetName="People" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeFilter="Person">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: I switched to Mvc Scaffolding instead. T4 is not as difficult as it seemed and the ability to use `foreach` in the package manager console makes scaffolding 70+ classes automatic.

Comment: can i see your solution please? ... i'm looking at this right now ... trying to build a business case for retiring MVP and one of my colleagues says he likes how dynamic data in webforms does that automatic view construction.

Answer (score 1):

The EntityDataSource control needs an ObjectContext (Database First context), not a DbContext (Code First context).  This tutorial shows how to use EntityDataSource and is less than a year old:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But David Ebbo says it works with EF 4.1 code first here [link](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/using-dynamic-data-with-ef-code-first.html)

Comment: Is there a section that shows how to do MVC AND Dynamic Data together? I have the data model all designed in MVC and I want to add dynamic data either as a second project or merge them together. I don't want to create a new data model for the dynamic data project.

Comment: I just tried a similar scenario (added Dynamic Data project to a solution with an MVC Code First project) using David Ebbo's Approach #1 and it is working.  Do you have |DataDirectory| in your connection strings?  If so you'll have to provide a complete address to the .sdf or .mdf in the MVC app's App_Data folder.

Comment: I think your context registration should look like this:  DefaultModel.RegisterContext(() => { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)new MvcApplication1.Models.Context()).ObjectContext; }, new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Can you explain how I can make the connection string reference another project? And is the string supposed to be static? IOW would it have to be manually edited after deployment?

Comment: Ok, I got them working from the same database using a database first approach. Now back to code first. Also, I am only deploying on one or two machines so no big deal if I have to manually edit the connection string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I believe you'll have to maintain the connection string in each project's Web.config file.  But you can set up Web.config transforms to make the changes automatically when you deploy.  See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12